# Change colour of buttons on click

Tags: javascript

I have two buttons which the user can click on. The objective is for the user to be able to click on the buttons and have it change colour which I have accomplished. But the issue is I want the colour to go back to the original colour when they click the other button and vis versa. Here is the code I have.

```
<div id='rightAlign'>
    <div id="but1">
        <button id="button1">Click Me</button>
        <button id="button2">Click Me</button>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
    var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");

    button1.addEventListener("click", function() {
        button1.style.backgroundColor = "red";

        button2.addEventListener("click", function() {
            button2.style.backgroundColor = "red";


        });
```

Comment: set background-color: ' ' of the other button on click.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the other `button`. Try the following:

```js
var button1 = document.getElementById("button1"); 
var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");
var button1Default, button2Default;
button1Default = button1.style.backgroundColor;
button2Default = button2.style.backgroundColor;

button1.addEventListener("click", function(){
  button1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  button2.style.backgroundColor = button2Default;
});

button2.addEventListener("click", function(){
  button2.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  button1.style.backgroundColor = button1Default;
});
```

```css
#button1,#button2 { padding: 15px 25px; font-size: 24px; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; outline: none; color: #fff; background-color: #4CAF50; border: none; border-radius: 15px; box-shadow: 0 9px #999; } 
#button1:hover {background-color: #3e8e41} 
#button1:active { box-shadow: 0 5px #666; transform: translateY(4px); }
```

```html
<div id='rightAlign'>
  <div id="but1">
    <button id="button1" onclick="">Click Me</button>
    <button id="button2">Click Me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if OP has already set background color to buttons. like `#button1 { background: green; }`

Comment: @Tushar It would already be defined as that element's "default background color" and would be set to that color. It's logical as long as you have a basic knowledge of JavaScript and CSS.

Comment: @TyQ. True. My bad.

Comment: @rayjay, I have changed the snippet according to your css. It will work dynamically with the css color of the button.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");    

button1.addEventListener("click", function(){
button1.style.backgroundColor = "red"
button2.style.backgroundColor = ''
})

button2.addEventListener("click", function(){
button2.style.backgroundColor = "red"
button1.style.backgroundColor = ''
})
```

```html
<div id='rightAlign'>
  <div id="but1">
    <button id="button1">Click Me</button>
    <button id="button2">Click Me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what i have in my CSS. 
        #button1 {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
}
        
#button1:hover {background-color: #3e8e41}

#button1:active {
  
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

Comment: @rayjay css won't have any effect when you are changing it with javascript. Just the hover effect will be same. Post your css and complete your question what you want to implement

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
var button1 = document.getElementById("button1"); 
var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");

 button1.addEventListener("click", function(){
   button1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
   button2.style.backgroundColor = "";
 });

 button2.addEventListener("click", function(){
   button2.style.backgroundColor = "red";
   button1.style.backgroundColor = "";
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <button id="button1">Click Me</button>
  <button id="button2">Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

looking for?